# Biztalk 2010: The property specified on the filter expression does not exist

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

After I deployed a new version of some assemblies and tried to start my send ports 
I keep getting this error:

> Could not enlist Send Port ''. The property specified on the filter expression does not exist.

What causes that error and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Is the name of the Send Port actually blank, or are you omitting it as it contains company information?

Answer (score 0):

Look under Schemas in for this BizTalk Application, you should see your property schema assuming the filter was based on custom properties.

Check that you've set the Application in the Visual Studio project properties otherwise the assembly gets deployed to the default App, BizTalk Application 1.

Failing that you could just be missing a reference within the BizTalk Application.